# Why the file is not created?

Tags: c, windows, driver

I tried to create a "txt" file using kernel driver.
The file is created successfully when I used "OSRLOADER" ,but when I tried to load the driver as a service using CreateService API, I cannot find the file

What is the problem?

A program that creates a service:

```
int main() {

SC_HANDLE schManager;
SC_HANDLE schService;
SC_HANDLE schopen;

schManager = OpenSCManagerA(0, 0,  SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
if (!schManager) {
    printf("Open SCM fails.\nError_Code: %d", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
printf("Open SCM Successfully.......\n");

schService = CreateServiceA(
    schManager,
    "file",
    "file",
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
    SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER,
    SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
    "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\CreateFile.sys",
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0
);

if (!schService) {
    printf("\nService fails.\nError_Code: %d", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
printf("Service Created Successfully.......\n");

schopen = OpenServiceA(schManager, "file",  SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

if (!schopen) {
    printf("\nService fails to open.\nError_Code: %d", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
printf("Service Opened Successfully.......\n");

StartServiceA(schService, 0, 0);

CloseHandle(schManager);
CloseHandle(schService);
CloseHandle(schopen);

return 0;}
```

....................................................................

The Driver:

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objattr;
UNICODE_STRING filename = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\c:\\test.txt");
NTSTATUS status;
HANDLE filehandle;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock = { 0 };

//Initialize an object for creating files ==> It will be used in ZwCreateFile()
InitializeObjectAttributes(&objattr, &filename, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);


status = ZwCreateFile(
    &filehandle,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    &objattr,
    &ioStatusBlock,
    NULL,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    FILE_OVERWRITE_IF,
    FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT,
    NULL,
    0
);

if (!status) {
    DbgPrint("Error While Creating file.......");
}
ZwClose(filehandle);
return STATUS_SUCCESS;}
```

Comment: Please add more information, e.g. what output did you get? The problem I found with the current information: the NTSTATUS value should use NT_SUCCESS to determine success or failure.

Comment: I tested it on windows 7 x64 bit, when I query the error code, it was 1275